# error CS0426: The type name 'UsrUserRole' does not exist in the type 'PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderType'

Tags: customization, acumatica

I want to set the default OrderType on SOOrder screen by current user login with user in role. So I create the new field on screen Order Type:SO201000 that selects the role name. For example: OrderType: C1 for userRole: 001A and OrderType: C2 for userRole: 001D.

On screen OrderType:SO201000 and UsrUserRole(New Field)

```
 [PXDBString(64)]
 [PXDefault()]
 [PXSelector(typeof(Search2<PX.SM.Roles.rolename>))]
 [PXUIField(DisplayName="User Role", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
```

On screen SOOrder: OrderType (Customized Existing Field)

```
 [PXDefault(typeof(Search2<SOOrderType.orderType,InnerJoin<PX.SM.UsersInRoles, On<PX.SM.UsersInRoles.rolename, Equal<SOOrderType.UsrUserRole>>>,Where<PX.SM.UsersInRoles.username, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
```

Default OrderType (Customized Existing Field)

```
 [PXSelector(typeof(Search5<SOOrderType.orderType,InnerJoin<SOOrderTypeOperation, On<SOOrderTypeOperation.orderType, Equal<SOOrderType.orderType>, And<SOOrderTypeOperation.operation, Equal<SOOrderType.defaultOperation>>>,LeftJoin<SOSetupApproval, On<SOOrderType.orderType, Equal<SOSetupApproval.orderType>>>>,Aggregate<GroupBy<SOOrderType.orderType>>>),DescriptionField = typeof(SOOrderTypeT.descr))]   [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<SOOrderTypeOperation.iNDocType,NotEqual<INTranType.transfer>, Or<FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.warehouse>>>), ErrorMessages.ElementDoesntExist, typeof(SOOrderType.orderType))]
 [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<SOOrderType.requireAllocation, NotEqual<True>, Or<AllocationAllowed>>), ErrorMessages.ElementDoesntExist, typeof(SOOrderType.orderType))]
 [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<SOOrderType.active,Equal<True>>), null)]
```

Comment: Is it not clear enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write a search, you are writing it to get the field you want. In this case, you want the value of SOOrderType.orderType.

If you are sure that Search in the PXDefault attribute is correct, may be you need to check the logic of Acumatica screen how it is assigning the value. May be there is some logic that overwrites your value.

Is UsrUserRole in an extension for SOOrderType? if then you should use it like YourExtension.UsrUserRole not SOOrderType.UsrUserRole

Comment: The main idea, I want to select SOOrder Type that sets for the role in Order Type screen. But now cannot select it.

Comment: It seems like on OrderType screen that I just created new field, it saved into table but it's not defined in SOOrderType so that's why it got error: The type name 'UsrUserRole' does not exist in the type 'PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderType'.

Comment: Is UsrUserRole in an extension for SOOrderType? if then you should use it like YourExtension.UsrUserRole not SOOrderType.UsrUserRole

Comment: I really don't know why SOOrderType don't have UsrUserRole because I have added it in OrderType screen already.

Comment: I changed as you told me like MyExtension.UsrUserRole so it works! Thanks.

Comment: On SOOrder Screen: I have OrderType: C1,C2,CS,SO,S1 and C1->userlogin A, C2->userlogin B,CS & SO->userlogin Admin, and S1->userlogin C. I want to select the Ordertype by userlogin, if userlogin= Admin so show the selector are CS & SO.

Comment: if your issue is resolved please mark the answer. if you have further questions, create new questions.